# Why the App doesn't reconnect to the BLE device when set autoConnect to true in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am develop in **Android and BLE**. I want the App **automatic reconnect** to the **BLE device** after the **BLE device** disconnect but come back in the range and advertising.

I use the following code to connect to the BLE device:

```
public void connect(final String address) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothLeService Connect function.");
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            //return false;
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);

    }
```

I have set the `AutoConnect` to the `true` , but it didn't reconnect when the BLE device has disconnect and come back in the range.

**Why the App doesn't reconnect to the BLE device when set autoConnect to true in Android?**

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The auto connect parameter determines whether to actively connect to the remote device (or) rather passively scan and finalize the connection when the remote device is in range.

But this does not mean that a peripheral that's been disconnected for days then reappears will be reconnected.

Generally, the first ever connection to a device should be direct (autoConnect set to false) and subsequent connections to known devices should be invoked with the autoConnect parameter set to true.

Also please note, the auto connect will only work when the device is still broadcasting. If not, then it will not work.

I would prefer that you re-connect manually when the device is disconnected. If in case you do end up following this, you would need a marker to determine whether the device was actually disconnected without the user consent.

If true then unbind/unregister your service/broadcast receiver and connect again using the **device address** which you must have saved previously.

Comment: What the time limit of BLE re-connect after device disconnect when autoConnect set to true in Android?

Comment: i am not sure to be honest, since i never found the auto connect feature to be completely reliable (at least in my case) and like i mentioned before i wrote my own code to re-connect with BLE which was far more effective and reliable.

Comment: Vikram, How sure are you of what 'autoconnect' does (when set to true)? What happens when one connects to multiple devices with autoconnect set to true and one does NOT close the BluetoothGatt object when the device disconnects?

Comment: I too have not found the autoConnect feature to be reliable, on different devices, the re-connection happens differently. Ex. the time taken to reconnect after a connectionInterval varies significantly i my experience.

Comment: @VikramEzhil can you please share the reconnect code for BLE

Answer (score -1):

As per my experimentation with the BLE devices it has different behavior in different builds like Kitkat and Lollipop. Even I have observed, using ScanCallback is not so reliable introduced in API level 24.

For auto connect to work the BLE device must be active.

For me i had to support kitkat and lollipop so while connecting gatt i called as:

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            gatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, executor);
        } else {
            gatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, executor);
        }
```

Now auto connect is working for me in both Lollipop and Kitkat.

Comment: Well now you just disable auto connect for non-kitkat? That means you will use direct connect with its implications of 30 seconds timeout and max 1 pending connection at a time.